# rails plugin for javascript/ajax sortable tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using dataTables to display the entries in rails model. One of my model has 5000+ records in it. Since dataTables plugin queries all of them at once, it takes forever to retrieve the records and then add it to the table. Tables does support pagination so I see 15 rows at a time, but its still slow.

Is there any other plugin which is faster or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The Shield UI Lite version (https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite) offers a free grid implementation and there is a really nice tutorial about implementing it in Ruby on Rails here https://www.shieldui.com/blogs/shieldui-jquery-grid-with-ruby-on-rails. You just need to tweak the application layout to remove the full version reference and add the Lite version to your application.js manifest.